# What Wii Remote input affects my throw in bowling?

Tags: wii-sports

In Wii Sports bowling, I can move my character's starting position back and forth, and change the initial angle of their throw.  But it seems that there are other properties of the throw that are determined by Wii Remote actions:

- Speed / strength of throw (obviously)
- "spin" on ball

What other things might I be missing, and what affects them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. When you let go of the ball

   If you let go earlier (before the character has walked all the way to the foul line), the ball has more time to curve if you put spin on it.  You can make the final angle of the ball more sharp by letting go earlier than you would have otherwise, assuming the same spin, and of course it will have drifted farther left or right.
2. Throwing the ball up / out

   Letting go of the ball when your / the character's arm is up / out affects it differently than letting go down low.  In general the higher you throw, the straighter the ball will go; it will be less affected by spin due to the "thump".  So if your goal is to curve the ball, you probably want to let go down low.

It's also interesting to note that spin can be put on the ball both by twisting your hand and by flicking left or right at the end of your throw.

I think that's all you missed.  I consider myself an expert because I got good enough for the game to start cheating on me (I got 10 strikes and then left a corner pin ... so unfair.  But I spared it up).

Comment: haha... I always think the game is cheating on me too :P. I have bowled so many 298's it is depressing.

Answer (score 3):

Basically:

- The acceleration of the remote towards the screen (emulating your motion to push and release the ball into the lane)
- The time you release the button (emulating when you let go of the ball)
- The rotation of your wrists/forearm closely following your thumb as the axis of rotation (rotation along the long axis of the controller if you hold the controller correctly, emulating the spin you put on the ball when you throw it)
- The rotation of your wrists in the direction perpendicular to you palm, closely following your wrist as the axis of rotation (rotation along the axis perpendicular to the face of the controller where your thumb rests if you hold the controller correctly, emulating the extra directional push you put on the ball when you throw it)