# How do I throw a hook in Kinect Sports Bowling?

Tags: kinect-sports, kinect

I was reading [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/what-wii-remote-input-affects-my-throw-in-bowling) about throwing a hook in Wii Sports bowling (which I can do), and it reminded me of the one time I was playing Kinect Sports Bowling with my friends and their child.

I'd never played Kinect Sports before, but I thought I remembered Wii Sports being a bit like real-life bowling, so I tried to do the same thing (basically, throw like I would if I were holding a real ball), and it didn't seem to work at all. Instead, I got what seemed to be a sequence of very straight throws: nice when I wanted to pick up the 7 or 10 pins, but not nice when I was throwing a first ball.

So I thought I would ask: what should I be doing to get my ball to hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hand (and arm) need to finish at the angle you want your hook to go.

For example a right handed bowler needs to finish with their right hand at their left sholder to get the ball to hook left.  Conversily to hook right the right hand should finish to the outside of the right shoulder.

Comment: Interesting, but reasonable. So it's the position rather than the rotation ... I will give this a try the next time I "bowl".

Comment: Kinect is awesome but not awesome enough to reliably and accurately calculate wrist rotation.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm just now playing again. You're exactly right: we should have watched the tutorial!